# How to handle very large data with Tableau

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, oracle-sqldeveloper, tableau-api

All,

I am using Tableau 9.0 to do data analysis. My data set is very large containing 100 billion records.

I want to use filter to filter out the data firstly. But, when I try to add filter on the specific column of the data in Tableau, it keep running... for ever. The reason is tableau wants to display all this field value to me with ascending order, then allow me to make selection. e.g to select only one or two value to filter...

But it keeps running due to 100 billion records. How to solve this problem? Could I switch off this function (display all specific field value..)? How to filter so large data sets?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pause Auto-Updates via the toolbar pause button before dragging a field to the filter shelf (or doing anything that you don't want to trigger a query refresh). Then either hit refresh or turn auto-updates back on when you want to run a query.

For discrete dimension filter, you can enter custom value lists to avoid querying to fill a list of items in the filter dialog.

Comment: Thanks. Alex, Do you mean I should also use custom sql query in tableau to filter the data source to get the smaller working data, then go to work sheet for analysis.

Comment: I mean do not use custom SQL queries in Tableau unless you have first made sure there is not a better alternative. Custom SQL is useful, but it defeats important query optimizations -- it forces Tableau to generate conservative possibly overly expensive queries because it does not know what you put in the custom SQL. There are many alternative ways to to access data efficiently in Tableau. Custom SQL is the catch-all feature to use in the rare cases where the other Tableau features don't give you the results you need. Even then, its more efficient to make a view on your database.

Comment: For large data sets, you might want to first make a data source level filter that reduces the volume of data to a smaller subset. Or better, make an extract with FILTERS that reduces the number of rows to a small subset, and hide the unused fields to reduce the number of columns. Then you can build the viz quickly with the fast extract, and then point to the original data source (again with appropriate filters). Do NOT try to make an extract that copies the entire data set obviously.

Comment: Thanks, Alex, to switch off the auto update and run filter firstly is the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can improve your performance by considering the following tips-

```
Use custom sql query in tableau to filter the data source to get the smaller working data.(data filtered at backend will be added advantage)

Hide unwanted fields from the data source pane.

Publish your data set to tableau server and then connect the tde server extract to tableau.
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't feel Tableau is the right tool for such a large data set. But check out this article on performance.
http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/database-query-performance

Comment: The sane approach for enormous data sets is to leave the data at the source, sending queries that return modest sized results that summarize the data. The insane approach is to fetch and display every data row. Combine that with filtering, caching and interactive drill down into subsets. The presentation layer speed depends on what queries the it sends and how quickly the database can perform them. That will take careful tuning and rule out some approaches that work for smaller data sets. These facts are the same in any visualization tool, Tableau or otherwise.